# Error en la sumatoria de Inputs - Jquery y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo este script que agrega un input y en el input total `<input type="number" name="total" id="total" value="0">` no me suma el input que viene por default, el resto me los suma y no me arroja ningun error.

Me podrían ayudar a resolverlo?

index.php

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_item_btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#show_item").prepend(`<div class="append_item"><div>
            <input type="text" name="product[]" required>
            <input type="number" class="precio-input" name="precio[]" required>
            <input type="number" class="cantidad-input" name="cantidad[]" required>
            <button class="remove_item_btn">Quitar</button>
            </div></div>`);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove_item_btn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let row_item = $(this).parent().parent();
    $(row_item).remove();
  });

  $(document).on('input', '.precio-input, .cantidad-input', function() {
    updateTotal();
  });

  function updateTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    $('.append_item').each(function(index, element) {
      const precio = parseFloat($(element).find('.precio-input').val()) || 0;
      const cantidad = parseFloat($(element).find('.cantidad-input').val()) || 0;
      total += precio * cantidad;
    });
    $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
  }

  $("#add_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#add_btn").val('Cargando...');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'action.php',
      method: 'post',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // $("#add_btn").val('Add');
        // $("#add_form")[0].reset();
        // $(".append_item").remove();
        // $("#show_alert").html(`<div></div>`);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST" id="add_form">
  <div id="show_item">
    <input type="text" name="product[]" required>
    <input type="number" class="precio-input" name="precio[]" required>
    <input type="number" class="cantidad-input" name="cantidad[]" required>
    <button class="add_item_btn">Agregar</button>
  </div>

  <input type="number" name="total" id="total" value="0">

  <input type="submit" value="add" id="add_btn">
</form>
```

action.php

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

// $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas','root','');

// $code = rand();
// $fecha = date('Y-m-d');

// foreach($_POST['product'] as $key => $value){
//  $sql = "INSERT INTO detalle (code, producto, precio, cantidad) VALUES (:code, :producto, :precio, :cantidad)";
//  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
//  $stmt->execute([
//      'code' => $code,
//      'producto' => $value,
//      'precio' => $_POST['precio'][$key],
//      'cantidad' => $_POST['cantidad'][$key],
//  ]);
// }

// $sql_venta = "INSERT INTO venta (code, fecha) VALUES (:code, :fecha)";
// $stmt_venta = $conn->prepare($sql_venta);
// $stmt_venta->execute(['code' => $code, 'fecha' => $fecha]);

// echo 'Ok';

echo $_POST['total'];

?>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: *no me suma el input que viene por default*, ¿qué input es ese?

Comment: Este fragmento es el que no me toma el precio: ` <div id="show_item">
    <input type="text" name="product[]" required>
    <input type="number" class="precio-input" name="precio[]" required>
    <input type="number" class="cantidad-input" name="cantidad[]" required>
    <button class="add_item_btn">Agregar</button>
  </div>`

Comment: El error radica en que los elementos que generas dinamicamente se generan dentro del contendor **append_item**, y los que ya tienes generados desde un principio nunca los recorres, para ello deberías recorrerlos también dentro de la misma función pero indicándole el contenedor **show_item**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te mencione en el comentario, el error radica en que creas una función que genera el contenedor con **inputs dinámicos** llamado `append_item` y recorres sus elementos en la funcion `updateTotal()`, los **inputs que mencionas como default** jamas los recorres, ya que se encuentran en el contenedor con **id="show_item"**. Te recomendaría generar un contenedor padre y dentro de ese con la clase `append_item` nombrar a los que ya están por defecto, y los generados dinamicamente también asignarles la misma clase pero dentro del contenedor padre `show_item` de esta manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_item_btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#show_item").prepend(`<div class="append_item">
            <input type="text" name="product[]" required>
            <input type="number" class="precio-input" name="precio[]" required>
            <input type="number" class="cantidad-input" name="cantidad[]" required>
            <button class="remove_item_btn">Quitar</button>
            </div>`);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove_item_btn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let row_item = $(this).parent();
    $(row_item).remove();
  });


  $(document).on('input', '.precio-input, .cantidad-input', function() {
    updateTotal();
  });

  function updateTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    $('.append_item').each(function(index, element) {
      const precio = parseFloat($(element).find('.precio-input').val()) || 0;
      const cantidad = parseFloat($(element).find('.cantidad-input').val()) || 0;
      total += precio * cantidad;
    });
    $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
  }

  $("#add_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#add_btn").val('Cargando...');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'action.php',
      method: 'post',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // $("#add_btn").val('Add');
        // $("#add_form")[0].reset();
        // $(".append_item").remove();
        // $("#show_alert").html(`<div></div>`);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST" id="add_form">
  <div id="show_item">
    <div class="append_item">
      <input type="text" name="product[]" required>
      <input type="number" class="precio-input" name="precio[]" required>
      <input type="number" class="cantidad-input" name="cantidad[]" required>
      <button class="add_item_btn">Agregar</button>
    </div>

    <input type="number" name="total" id="total" value="0">

    <input type="submit" value="add" id="add_btn">
  </div>

</form>
```

**Nota:** Considera que al eliminar los **inputs dinámicos** se deberían de restar de la sumatoria total.

Comment: Muchas gracias, entiendo a lo que apuntas, pero de esta forma deja de funcionar la opción de quitar los input. El `remove_item_btn` puede ir fuera de la funcion `updateTotal()`?

Comment: Cierto, modifico el código, andaba haciendo pruebas y se me paso corregirlo.

Comment: Ya lo corregí, también observa que corregí el **preppend**, ya que generabas dos div  cosa que no es necesaria, en el **remove** ya solo es con un **parent** para acceder contenedor padre que detona el evento.

Comment: No hay problema, muchas gracias igual. Con lo que tu me dices al menos no estaba errado yo, jajajaja.